# Appending 0s to an incomplete macro parameter list

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have the following couple of **C** preprocessor macros that I use:

```
#define TAKE4(a1, a2, a3, a4, ...) a1, a2, a3, a4
#define FILL_PARAMS(...) TAKE4(__VA_ARGS__, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

When calling `FILL_PARAMS` with 1, 2, or 3 parameters, the later (unspecified) are turned into 0s as expected, but when giving no arguments there's an error.

Is there a way to add support for no-parameters?

Clarification:
Currently the following uses are supported:

```
FILL_PARAMS(1)         // => 1, 0, 0, 0
FILL_PARAMS(1, 2)      // => 1, 2, 0, 0
FILL_PARAMS(1, 2, 3)   // => 1, 2, 3, 0
```

And I want to add support for the following edge case:

```
FILL_PARAMS()          // => 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Help will be welcome.

Comment: It can be done with some effort.  Take a look at [how it was done here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713046/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-c-macro/34713272)

Comment: What's wrong with using `FILL_PARAMS(0)` for the empty case?

Comment: @Leandros . But this can be a limitation too..

Comment: Because when I have to choose between inelegant implementation and inelegant API, I'd rather take inelegant implementation and stop the inelegance at the lowest possible level.

Comment: To highlight the core problem here, the preprocessor can't tell the difference between no parameter and an empty parameter, hence the need for one of the hackish solutions that others have described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a hack-ish solution:

```
#define TAKE4(a1, a2, a3, a4, ...) a1, a2, a3, a4
#define FILL_PARAMS(...) TAKE4( __VA_ARGS__ + 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

That works with at-least the following test-cases.

```
int i = 120;
printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", FILL_PARAMS());
printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", FILL_PARAMS(i));
printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", FILL_PARAMS(1));
printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", FILL_PARAMS(1, 2));
printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", FILL_PARAMS(1, 2, 3));
printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", FILL_PARAMS(1, 2, 3, 4));
printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", FILL_PARAMS(1, 2, 3, i));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in multiple ways, the most simple way is to use

```
FILL_PARAMS(0)
```

as the empty case.

Another, more complicated, and cumbersome to use way is to always have the comma following the last parameter:

```
#define TAKE4(a1, a2, a3, a4, ...) a1, a2, a3, a4
#define FILL_PARAMS(...) TAKE4(__VA_ARGS__ 0, 0, 0, 0)

/* called like: */
FILL_PARAMS()
FILL_PARAMS(1,)
FILL_PARAMS(1,2,)
FILL_PARAMS(1,2,3,)
```

Or by being a little creative with GCCs comma swallowing extension:

```
#define TAKE4(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, ...) a2, a3, a4, a5
#define FILL_PARAMS(...) TAKE4(0, ##__VA_ARGS__, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```